# Why is my web service saying I'm giving it a bad request?

Tags: c#, json, web-services

Pulling my hair out over here, please help. All I want is a POST web service that takes a string parameter (it will be json) and then parse it into a JObject so I can get data from it. **I do not want to match it to a .NET object. That is not  an option.**

I have the following Web Service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string ProcessJsonData(string jsonData);

public string ProcessJsonData(string jsonData)
{
    JObject JObj = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
    return "Success";
}
```

I want both AJAX calls and code behind calls to work. But I keep getting bad request error (400).

Here's what I'm doing in the Javascript:

(just assume jsonObject is a correctly formatted json string (used it in other test and jsonlite.come or whatever has verified it)

```
var dataObj = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: dataObj,
        url: "http://blabalblafdsfs/ProcessJsonData",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    })

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://blabalblafdsfs/ProcessJsonData?jsonData=" + dataObj,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    })
```

Neither of those methods work.
Here is my code behind method:

```
string testJson = @"{
 ""Questions"":[
    {""Code"":""s1"",""Questions"":""Q1,Q2""},
    {""Code"":""s2"",""Questions"":""Q1,Q2,Q3""},
    {""Code"":""s3"",""Questions"":""Q1,Q2,Q4""},
    {""Code"":""s4"",""Questions"":""Q1,Q2,Q5""}
  ]
}";
string response;
        string responseBody;

        try
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://blabalblafdsfs/ProcessJsonData", UriKind.Absolute);
            response = client.UploadString(uri, "POST", testJson);
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            response = we.ToString();
        }

        try
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                NameValueCollection requestParameters = new NameValueCollection();
                Uri uri = new Uri("http://blabalblafdsfs/ProcessJsonData", UriKind.Absolute);
                response = client.UploadString(uri, "POST", testJson);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            response = we.ToString();
        }
```

Again, no success. All help is appreciated.

Comment: *"just assume is a correctly formatted json string"*: If I had written that sentence myself, I'd suddenly feel icy knives in my heart and go find out where my JSON string was misformatted.

Comment: just a guess but try passing method=POST in the url in the AJAX instead of using type as POST (i had a similar issue with FB API and this solved it)

Comment: If you don't want it mapped to a C# class, try setting the request and response to text instead of JSON.  You are, after all, accepting and returning a string.

Comment: Ed Plunkett, I know right? But it's 100% not the cause. Inarilo, what do you mean? How do I do that Paul?